# TransactionScope commits updates without calling .Complete() but not inserts

Tags: c#, .net, transactions

I have a transacationScope that surrounds some functions. These functions each do database calls of either inserts or updates.

```
 using (var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions()
            {
                IsolationLevel =
                    IsolationLevel.Serializable,
                Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15, 0)
            }))
            {
                    DoStuff(arg!, arg2);
                    ts.Complete(); //This had to be added to commit the changes for inserts (updates worked), otherwise data was being rolled back
            }
```

With `ts.Complete();` inserts and updates are committed to the database, without only updates are. Could someone please explain why?

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem, so how did you solve the problem of committing changes without calling Complete()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That suggests your updates are not part of the transaction. That could mean:

- the updates were done on a connection that already existed before you started the transaction-scope
- there was an explicit nested new-transaction or no-transaction
- unicorns

To confirm: without the Complete, nothing in the transaction is committed

Comment: Without the Complete() updates are committed, inserts are not. The same stored procs are called for both inserting and updating data (passing in Sql Table types and figuring whether to insert or update the data based on flags)

Comment: @Ben we need to see DoStuff. My thoughts on "how" remain as per this answer

Comment: though, about the first reason, the connection can exist before but has to be open after.